# What is the difference between mapDispatchToProps and matchDispatchToProps

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

The title explains the questions.

I am using redux to change state of users to active or in-active users.

In matchDispatchToProps:

```
function matchDispatchToProps(dispatch){
  return bindActionCreators({selectUser: selectUser}, dispatch);
}
```

In case of mapDispatchToProps :

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    dispatch({selectUser: selectUser})
})
```

Please explain the difference between these.

Comment: what do you mean by difference? Both cases result in the same thing...

Comment: so there should be some difference to create two ways. some benefits and disadvantages depending on situations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two things here.

First, the proper name of the second argument to `connect()` is called `mapDispatchToProps`.  It is also frequently referred to as `mapDispatch`.  But, like any function call in JS, it doesn't matter what *you* call *your* variable - you can call your function `mapDispatchToProps`, `mapDispatch`, `fred`, or `someFunctionName`.  (That said, I have no idea why you're calling it *`matchDispatchToProps`*, or where you heard that name.)

Second, your two example functions there are very different.  The intent of a `mapDispatch` function is to return an object, and each key/value in the object will become a prop for the component.  Normally, you would return bound-up action creator functions inside that object, so that the component will receive props like `this.props.doSomeWork()`.  Your first example, which does `return bindActionCreators({selectUser}, dispatch)`, will correctly do that.

Your second example does not appear to be valid JS syntax:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    dispatch({selectUser: selectUser})
})
```

We've got an arrow function that immediately returns an object, but instead of declaring key/value pairs in the object, it looks like it's trying to call `dispatch` immediately.  That's not valid at all.

Answer (score 8):

`matchDispatchToProps` isn't a standard reference in `react-redux`. I will give you an overview of how the [connect](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options) HoC works.

The `connect` HoC takes four arguments; `mapStateToProps`, `mapDispatchToProps`, `mergeProps`, and `options`. In `mapStateToProps` you assign what information in your store you want to be available inside the component as follows:

```
mapStateToProps = ( state ) => ({
    user: state.user
});
```

In `mapDispatchToProps` you provide functions as props to your component that have access to the `dispatch` method of your store as follows:

```
mapDispatchToProps = ( dispatch ) => ({
    updateUser: ( user ) => {
        dispatch( updateUser( user ) );
    }
});
```

**Note**: `updateUser` is an `actionCreater` you would have made.

You would then use them with the `connect` HoC as follows:

`MyConnectedComponent = connect( mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps )( MyComponent );`

Now you can use `<MyConnectedComponent />` and inside of the `<MyComponent />` code you have access to the `({ user, updateUser })` properties.

**Note**: `connect` can take `null` arguments as well. `connect()( Component )` will make `dispatch` available in your component as a prop. This is the default setting without any arguments. You can also `connect( null, mapDispatchToProps )( Component )` to make `updateUser` a prop in the component without connecting the component to the store. You could also `connect( mapStateToProps )( Component )` if you wanted access to `user` from the store, but had no need to dispatch from within the component.

**Additional information**

*[mergeProps(stateProps, dispatchProps, ownProps): props] (Function):*

> If specified, it is passed the result of mapStateToProps(), mapDispatchToProps(), and the parent props. The plain object you return from it will be passed as props to the wrapped component. You may specify this function to select a slice of the state based on props, or to bind action creators to a particular variable from props. If you omit it, Object.assign({}, ownProps, stateProps, dispatchProps) is used by default.

*[options] (Object)*

> If specified, further customizes the behavior of the connector. In addition to the options passable to [connectAdvanced()](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectadvancedselectorfactory-connectoptions) (see those below), connect() accepts these additional options:

- [pure] (Boolean): If true, connect() will avoid re-renders and calls to mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps, and mergeProps if the relevant state/props objects remain equal based on their respective equality checks. Assumes that the wrapped component is a “pure” component and does not rely on any input or state other than its props and the selected Redux store’s state. Default value: true
- [areStatesEqual] (Function): When pure, compares incoming store state to its previous value. Default value: strictEqual (===)
- [areOwnPropsEqual] (Function): When pure, compares incoming props to its previous value. Default value: shallowEqual
- [areStatePropsEqual] (Function): When pure, compares the result of mapStateToProps to its previous value. Default value: shallowEqual
- [areMergedPropsEqual] (Function): When pure, compares the result of mergeProps to its previous value. Default value: shallowEqual
- [storeKey] (String): The key of the context from where to read the store. You probably only need this if you are in the inadvisable position of having multiple stores. Default value: 'store'

Complete documetion can be found at [reactjs/react-redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux).

Answer (score 1):

I believe you must have heard the term `matchDispatchToProps` from Bucky's ReactJS & Redux tutorials.

The common name for this function is actually `mapDispatchToProps`.

But I am not going to say that Bucky made a mistake, because really, this function can be called anything as long as you pass the same name to the second argument of your `connect()` method.

**Example:**

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return bindActionCreators({selectUser}, dispatch);
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    user: state.user,
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(myComponent);
```

If you aren't mapping state to props, then the first argument can be `null`

**Example:**

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return bindActionCreators({selectUser}, dispatch);
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(myComponent);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a good question to remind us how as developers we sometimes confuse convention with requirement after doing something for such a long time.

Technically, we can call it anything we want, it does not have to be `mapStateToProps` or `mapDispatchToProps`, but by convention this is what we call them because it makes our jobs easier when we have this level of consistency.

So the only difference is in the naming convention, these are not built-in functions that do something uniquely specific between each other. In fact, the latter is not conventionally used, I am referring to your matchDispatchToProps, but you certainly can use it if you want to.